# ASPPDFLib Could not create an object of type 'Persits.Pdf'

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am facing the above problem. I have some piece of legacy code which creates pdf. This code runs on server but on my pc i am getting exception.

The piece of code that give me the exception is:

```
IPdfManager objPDFTarget = (IPdfManager)Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf");
```

And the exception is

```
 Could not create an object of type 'Persits.Pdf'.
```

I have tryied

1. `IPdfManager objPDFTarget = new PdfManager();`
     Blows
2. `Type ExcelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AcroPDF.PDF");
                   object ExcelInst = Activator.CreateInstance(ExcelType);
                   ExcelType.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,
                       ExcelInst, new object[1] { true });
                   IPdfManager objPDFTarget =  (IPdfManager)ExcelInst;`
     Blows

I have published on my local iis and i have given full access to IIS_IUSR but nothing.

Is web applications using asp.net, .net 3.5 framework.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that in order to debug this piece of code i must have installed aspPdf setup with a key and only the dll was not enough.